# How do I count merged cells separately in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I'm using `countif(a1:a10, "*")` to sum the number of names in a guest list. However, some cells have been merged, e.g. for married couples or families where only one name is supplied.

See below for a concrete example, where `(+ x)` are merged with the cell above:

```
   |      A        |       B        |
1  | Cheah         |  Teo           |
2  | Hadi's Family |  Robinson      |
3  |  (+ wife)     |  Müller        |
4  |  (+ son)      |  Chan          |
5  | Ganesan       |  Yeong         |
6  | Chng          |   (+ wife)     |
7  | Tan           |  Ng            |
8  | Williams      |   (+ husband)  |
9  | Brecht        |   (+ daughter) |
10 | Ahmad         |                |
```

In the example above, I would like to obtain 10 in column A and 9 in column B.

I've seen @MaxMakhrov's suggestion of last non-empty row, but haven't been able to get a working solution out of it yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: The merged cells will always be considered blanks (other than the top left cell), will there be any other blank cells in the range that are not to be considered guests? If not, you could just use your current formula and add it to `COUNTBLANK(A1:A10)`

Comment: @Jordan yes, I have blank cells where a guest is not already there. Pity there isn't an `ismerged()` check or flag. @pnuts I will look at `=row()`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The formula of finding last non-empty row may help:

`=MAX(FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A<>""))`

But it will give the wrong result if last cells are merged:

Example:

```
1   a
2     
3   b  > merged
4
```

Last non-emty row is 2 in example above because cells 2,3,4 are merged.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting perspective! I tried with `max - min` of this formula, but it didn't quite work.

Comment: No, the formula itself works, but the merged last cell scenario failed as you described.